# VBA Do Loop changing variables

Tags: excel, vba, loops, do-loops

I have a code that copies column of data from one sheet and to another. I would like integrate a do loop so that I don't have to repeat the same commands for each column.

```
Dim LastRow As Long

Sheets("PWR 2 DATA CAPTURE SHEET Shared").Select
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
'MsgBox LastRow

Dim x As Integer


Sheets("PWR 2 DATA CAPTURE SHEET Shared").Select
Dim Copyrange1 As String
Startrow = 3
Let Copyrange1 = "B" & Startrow & ":" & "B" & LastRow
Range(Copyrange1).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("PWR2 data capture sheet ").Select
Range("B3").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

I want '1' after copyrange to change until '20', and 'B' to change from C, D, E,F,G,H,I,... Until 'AA' which is corresponds to the columns excel.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Look at using a `For Each...` type loop across multiple columns.  Also you don't need to use `.Select`, just refer to the range directly for faster execution.

Comment: Instead of using Copyrange1 = "B" & Startrow & ":" & "B" & LastRow I recommend to use this Range(Cells(Startrow, x), Cells(LastRow, x).Copy then You can iterate by x in Your loop and x will mean column that You want to copy. So You can use loop e. g. For x = 2 To 22 and at the end of loop Next x.